# Firebase read/write rules with Flutter not working?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, flutter

I'm having trouble with permissions for my Firebase Security Rules.  I'm logging the following errors..

```
[Firebase/Database][I-RDB03812] Listener at /users/4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891/Following/4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891 failed: permission_denied
[Firebase/Database][I-RDB03812] Listener at /UserVideo/4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891 failed: permission_denied
[Firebase/Database][I-RDB03428] Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "displayName" at /users to your security rules for better performance
```

Here is my rule structure:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$user_id": {".write": true, ".read": true}

  }
}
```

Here is how I'm structuring my data...

```
 UserVideo
     080d4874-47d9-4f4e-b815-9b8dc9c8a2ba
     13566fd4-047b-4d62-b2e5-e885e6667430
     2bd7038f-5490-470e-94eb-87695e4b1071
     2d84a15b-d0aa-4671-9f59-02f9d2ac5207
     3af71559-5c51-40c6-b2aa-8631671c2c25
     3fFH6evUANf3WDbDS3caiQu9crD3
     4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891
        Vid1
        Vid10
        Vid2
        Vid3

users
 4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891
  FollowedBy
    followedBy: 
      2
 Following
    4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891
 displayName: 
   "Charles"
 photo: 
   "placeholder"
```

My assumption was that my rule would let a user read and write to any available path, but I guess I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into this issue earlier. I looks like you are not using uid's but rather another id instance. The way to get the uid from the firebase instance is as follows:

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

var tempUser = await auth.currentUser();
currentUser= tempUser.uid;
```

Make sure you are pushing to the uid child under the root.

```
reference.child(currentUser).push().set({                                        
  'video': 080d4874-47d9-4f4e-b815-9b8dc9c8a2ba,                                               
});
```

Finally, set your read and write rules in firebase like this.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$user_id": {
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id",
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id"
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: You're right I'm not correctly authenticating throughout my app for some reason.  I looked over my SWIFT code and `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().uid` is what I used.  In Flutter `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` returns an error that currentUser is not a function.  Any idea on how to correctly authenticate throughout the app?

Comment: I have never really used swift, but check out this link from the Flutter SDK site. [https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#5](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#5) The main function you should focus on is the `_ensureLoggedIn()`. This function will allow you to let users login through Google and the way to get the UID can be seen referenced from my answer above once _ensureLoggedIn() is called